# Mark A Guest as organizer in Google calendar event

Tags: google-calendar

When I create an event in google calendar, It makes me organizer of that event. but some times its not the case that i am actually organizing it. So I was trying to make a guest as organizer but couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the owner of the event both in the detail view (More actions -> Change owner) and in the overview (... -> Change owner). See screenshots. Afaik the new owner has to accept before anything is actually changed.

[image: Change owner in event details]
[image: Change owner in event overview]